# SetWindowsHookEx for Mac OS X?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, macos, hook

Windows hooks allows you to poke inside other processes and sometimes alter their behaviors.

Is there such thing for Mac OS X?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`SetWindowsHookEx` is more like the old `InputManager` hack, in the sense that you change the code of an app from inside a shared library / a plugin loaded to it.

See [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) for a ready-made code injector to another process. For Objective-C classes, you then need to use [method swizzling](http://www.google.com/search?q=method_exchangeimplementations). I haven't tried replacing C functions / C++ classes myself, but surely it can be done using [mach_override](http://www.google.com/search?q=mach_override). See also [this blog post](http://www.core.dk/~lp/).

But usually if you want to modify a GUI app, tapping into Objective-C classes would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Quartz event taps can monitor and modify low-level events such as keystrokes and mouse clicks, subject to some restrictions.  Can you tell more about what you want to do?

Comment: Let's say I wanted to hook the function that loads asdf.dylib.
The ideia is to force an application to load my own customized version of asdf.dylib , without using the DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES trick.

Answer (score -1):

What are you trying to accomplish, specifically? Can you explain why you want the Mac OS X equivalent of `SetWindowsHookEx()`? (Short answer: there isn't one. Medium answer: just about everything you can do with `SetWindowsHookEx()` on Windows can be done on Mac OS X in some other, more OO way.)

Comment: On windows `SetWindowsHookEx` can help you to receive events from **other** processes. Such as window closing, window maximize...etc. Are you sure that this could be done on Mac OS X?

Comment: This is a very old answer to a very old question. :) I was saying that, if we knew the problem the original developer was trying to solve, we could recommend alternate approaches.