# Keylogger in Xcode?

Tags: macos

EDIT: This question was exceptionally dumb and made me look like a script kiddie, which I am not.

I originally just wanted to know how key strokes could be sent and listened for on Mac OSX and whether or not that was actually possible.

Comment: A budding script kiddie, I see...

Comment: Read this book : http://osxbook.com/ . What you're asking has nothing to do with Xcode by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258312/176769) has some great tips.