# pyHook alternative for OSX

Tags: python, macos, cocoa, python-3.x, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to find a listener for global keyboard events that works on OSX however all I've found is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994750/something-like-pyhook-on-os-x). Could anyone further explain what the reply regarding Cocoa/Quartz requires? I'm still a beginner in python so I'm very confused as to how those functions are called from a python script. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the question you referenced there is an answer with link to SelfSpy tool that seems to support Cocoa/Quartz: https://github.com/gurgeh/selfspy/blob/master/osx-requirements.txt

Comment: Looks great! Where would I start to learn how to use those libraries?